# Expansion normal forms of confluent term rewriting systems

Tags: lo.logic, term-rewriting-systems, normalization

Suppose one has two rewrite rules $\to^\eta,\to^\beta$, both of which are confluent and such that $\to^A := \to^{(\eta \cup \beta)}$ is also confluent.  Define a **$\beta$-normal form relative to $\eta$** to be $m$ such that

- $m$ is a $\beta$ normal form;
- $m \to^\eta n$ implies $n \to_{\beta}^* m$

One may think of $\to^\eta$ as being some kind of expansion that could prevent any term from having an $\to^A$ normal form.

Does anyone know of a definition like this, and/or nice properties such as: "relative normal forms if they exist are unique."

One *can* show that if $\eta$ requests $\beta^*$ : i.e. if there is a divergence between $n \to^\eta n'$ and $n \to_{\beta}^* n''$ then there is a join $n' \to_{\beta}^* m$ and $n'' \to^\eta \cdot \to_\beta^* m$, then relative normal forms (if they exist) are unique.

In fact, one can show that if the confluence of $\to^A$ is proved by decreasing diagrams with $\eta$ bigger than $\beta$, then again the property holds.  Essentially one proves the following first: if $m$ is a relative normal form with

$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
 s & \ra{\eta} & t \\ 
\da{\beta^*}\\
 m
\end{array}$

then $t \to_\beta^* m$.

The above then implies that any $\to^A$ sequence leaving a relative normal form will return by a $\beta$ sequence.  This in turn, along with the confluence of $\to^A$ can be used to show that relative normal forms are unique.

I can certainly fill in the details if anyone likes; however, this seems like something that should be generally true.  Does anyone know of any such results or counterexamples?